# PPTP Doesn't Connect - 12.04, 13.10, 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp, pptpd

Currently tested on Ubunutu 14.04, 13.10, and 12.04, I'm trying to connect to my VPN provider using PPTP. I've followed various instructions including the ones given to me by my provider only for them not to work.

On a fresh install of ubuntu I run the following (the usual bits):

```
apt-get install network-manager-pptp pptp-linux
```

Afterwards I fill in the usual config in Network Manager, including enabling MPPE. My VPN attempts to connect but in the end fails. This is what my syslog looks like before and after trying to connect. To make sure my VPN provider and creds work I've tested on my Mac without issue. What is it I'm doing wrong? Any help is appcrieated.

```
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 1530
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: init (1)
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN connection 'VPN connection 1' (Connect) reply received.
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: Using interface ppp0
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pptp[1537]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
May 13 18:53:28 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
May 13 18:53:29 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
May 13 18:53:29 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
May 13 18:53:29 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 35968).
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: Connection terminated.
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: Modem hangup
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pptp[1537]: nm-pptp-service-1530 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:204]: short read (-1): Input/output error
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pptp[1537]: nm-pptp-service-1530 warn[decaps_hdlc:pptp_gre.c:216]: pppd may have shutdown, see pppd log
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pppd[1532]: Exit.
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:234]: Closing connection (unhandled)
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox pptp[1543]: nm-pptp-service-1530 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
May 13 18:53:59 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
May 13 18:54:04 user-VirtualBox NetworkManager[688]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```